# Is there the way how to transform this kind of code into cycle for n-dimension?

Tags: r, function, loops, formula, cycle

I have this code for n = 4

```
b_11 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[1] - wi[1] + 1); b_11
b_12 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[1] - wi[2] + 1); b_12
b_13 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[1] - wi[3] + 1); b_13
b_14 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[1] - wi[4] + 1); b_14

b_21 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[2] - wi[1] + 1); b_21
b_22 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[2] - wi[2] + 1); b_22
b_23 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[2] - wi[3] + 1); b_23
b_24 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[2] - wi[4] + 1); b_24

b_31 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[3] - wi[1] + 1); b_31
b_32 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[3] - wi[2] + 1); b_32
b_33 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[3] - wi[3] + 1); b_33
b_34 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[3] - wi[4] + 1); b_34

b_41 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[4] - wi[1] + 1); b_41
b_42 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[4] - wi[2] + 1); b_42
b_43 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[4] - wi[3] + 1); b_43
b_44 <- (1 / 2) * (wi[4] - wi[4] + 1); b_44



trB <- c(b_11, b_12, b_13, b_14,
         b_21, b_22, b_23, b_24,
         b_31, b_32, b_33, b_34,
         b_41, b_42, b_43, b_44)
```

Is there any way how to simplify (or make cycle) it for other cases, where n could be bigger than 4?
(wi[i] is a vector).

Formulas in case this helps:

[image: formulas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be vectorised as:

```
set.seed(0)
wi <- runif(4)  #or whatever   
0.5* (outer(wi,wi,"-")+1)
```

to produce a matrix. Now the code is independent of the length of `wi`. If you prefer the vector that you currently have, the output could be reshaped with:

```
c(t(0.5* (outer(wi,wi,"-")+1)))
```

Comment: OMG, this actually works just perfectly fine! Thank you!